# Unable to add Nodes or shapes in Jsplumb community edition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, jsplumb

I am using the `@jsplumb/browser-ui` to create some `Nodes` within my `Nuxtjs/Vuejs`  application like as mentioned in their [documentation](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/demonstration/flowchart). But I would like to create the Nodes at run-time. I am unable to do it.

I would like to create the `nodes/rectangle` shapes whenever the user clicks on the `Add Event` button. So rather than creating the `Nodes` static way I would like to create it dynamically/run time based on the button click. I am not understanding how to do it using `jsPlumb` [documentation](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/demonstration/flowchart) how to do it as they don't have a specific code sample to achieve the same.

Following is the code I have:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @click="addConnector()">
            Add Connector
          </button>&nbsp;
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @click="addNode()">
            Add Event
          </button>&nbsp;
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" @click="submitEvents()">
            Submit
          </button>&nbsp;
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div id="diagram" ref="diagram" style="position: relative; width:100%; height:100%;" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
let jsPlumb = null

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      nodeCounter: 0,
      nodeArray: [],
      connectorCounter: 0,
      connectorArray: [],
      allEventsInfoArray: []
    }
  },
  async mounted () {
    if (process.browser) {
      const jsPlumbBrowserUI = await import('@jsplumb/browser-ui')

      jsPlumb = jsPlumbBrowserUI.newInstance({
        dragOptions: {
          cursor: 'pointer',
          zIndex: 2000
        },
        container: this.$refs.diagram
      })

      console.log(jsPlumb)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // On click of Add Node button create the draggable node into the jsPlumb canvas
    addNode () {
      // const container = "<button class='btn btn-info' id='container_" + this.nodeCounter + "'></button>"
      this.nodeCounter++
    },
    // On click of Add Connector button create the draggable node into the jsPlumb canvas
    addConnector () {
      console.log('Add Connector : ')

      jsPlumb.connect({
        anchor: 'AutoDefault',
        endpoints: ['Dot', 'Blank'],
        overlays: [
          { type: 'Arrow', options: { location: 1 } },
          {
            type: 'Label',
            options: { label: 'foo', location: 0.25, id: 'myLabel' }
          }
        ]
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the difference and it may be hard for the next reader too. Can you please give more info about what exactly is a node generation at runtime?

Comment: @kissu I am sorry for maybe an incomplete question. I have modified the question hopefully it is easy to understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping this answer would be helpful to someone in the future:

As per the response from contributors [GitHub](https://github.com/jsplumb/jsplumb/issues/1068), we cannot create the `Nodes/Shapes` within the `Jsplumb community edition`.

Instead of `Jsplumb`, I started using the `DrawFlow` library which is just awesome and has all the requirements that I needed for my application.